# Android notification intent with extras is always null

Tags: android-intent, android-notifications

I'm developing an app that can create multiple alarms, and these alarms send notifications to the user, so they can tap the notification and that leads to an activity with the alarm details which I want to display depending on the value of the extras, but my extras are always null, I don't understand what it's wrong.. I already searched a lot for questions and nothing seems to solve my problem.

This is where a create the alarm with a unique id each one. "item.getID()"

**NewAlarm.java**

```
        firstTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

        intervalTime = (1000 * 60 * 4); // 4 minutes

        // crear el pending intent y la alarma
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("ID", item.getID());
        intent.putExtra("MEDICINA", item.getMedicina());

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, item.getID(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstTime, intervalTime, pendingIntent);
```

**AlarmBroadcastReceiver.java**

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    try {

        int notifID = intent.getExtras().getInt("ID");
        String medicina = intent.getExtras().getString("MEDICINA");

        Intent alarmDetailsIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmDetails.class);
        alarmDetailsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("ID", notifID);
        intent.putExtra("MEDICINA", medicina);

        PendingIntent piDetails = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notifID, alarmDetailsIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mbBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        mbBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_my_calendar);
        mbBuilder.setContentTitle("Medic Reminder");
        mbBuilder.setContentText(medicina);
        mbBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{100, 250, 100, 500});
        mbBuilder.setContentIntent(piDetails);

        notificationManager.notify(notifID, mbBuilder.build());

    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and when the user clicks on the notification, will have to open an activity and show details of the alarm with the ID extra, but getIntent.getExtras() is always NULL.

**AlarmDetails.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recordatorio_alarma);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null){

        try {

            int notifID = extras.getInt("ID");
            String medicina = extras.getString("MEDICINA");

            TextView txtMedicina = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMedicinaAlarma);
            txtMedicina.setText("Medicina de prueba");

            Button btnCerrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStopAlarm);
            btnCerrar.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    finish();
                }
            });

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.cancel(notifID);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want getStringExtra(), not getExtras().getString().  That takes care of the case where you don't have any extras yet.

Comment: but doing this is not the same??
`Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();`
`int notifID = extras.getInt("ID");`
`String medicina = extras.getString("MEDICINA");`

Comment: The point is that MEDICINA is not among your extras.  In fact, you have not set extras, which is why getExtras() returns null.  That's what I would focus on.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: of course it is:
Intent alarmDetailsIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmDetails.class);
        alarmDetailsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("ID", notifID);
        intent.putExtra("MEDICINA", medicina);

Comment: It is clear that the extras are not being set, which is why getExtras() is returning null.  All that I can think of is that you are modifying the extras in a thread in which the parent was not created, or that you are getting the extras before you set them.

Answer (score 6):

i found my mistake!

```
    Intent alarmDetailsIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmDetails.class);
    alarmDetailsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("ID", notifID);
    intent.putExtra("MEDICINA", medicina);
```

must be:

```
    alarmDetailsIntent.putExtra("ID", notifID);
    alarmDetailsIntent.putExtra("MEDICINA", medicina);
```

Comment: I cannot believe I was making this exact mistake!

Answer (score 0):

When the app is in the background or killed state, Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) delivers the message payload directly to the system tray, and it doesn't invoke the onMessageReceived() method of your FirebaseMessagingService. Instead, if the user taps on the notification, the system will launch your app's launcher Activity (or the Activity specified in the notification's PendingIntent) and deliver the message data via the intent extras.

To handle this scenario and navigate to a specific fragment when the notification is clicked, you need to retrieve the notification data from the intent extras in your launcher Activity (or the Activity specified in the PendingIntent) and then navigate to the desired fragment based on that data.

Here's how you can modify your launcher Activity to handle the notification data and navigate to the appropriate fragment:

```
class LauncherActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    // Check if the launcher Activity was launched from a notification
    if (intent?.extras != null) {
        val notificationCode = intent.getStringExtra("notificationCode")
        if (notificationCode == "ParcelExpired") {
            // Navigate to the desired fragment based on the notification data
            val intent = Intent(this, ParcelsActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("notificationCode", notificationCode)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    // Finish the launcher Activity to prevent it from showing in the back stack
    finish()
}
```

}